# Pygame mixer only plays one sound at a time

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code:

```
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050,size=-16,channels=4)
sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound1.wav')
sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound2.wav')
chan1 = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
chan2 = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
chan1.queue(sound1)
chan2.queue(sound2)
time.sleep(10)
```

I would think it would play `sound1` and `sound2` simultaneously (`queue` is non-blocking and the code immediately hits the sleep).
Instead, it plays `sound1` and then plays `sound2` when `sound1` is finished.

I've confirmed both channels are distinct objects in memory so find_channel isn't returning the same channel.  Is there something I'm missing or does pygame not handle this?

Comment: Couldn't that be because the program seems to be linear... you call `sound1` before `sound2`

Comment: are the sounds long enough to see the difference?

Comment: sound1 is about 3 seconds long and sound2 is about 6 seconds long and they are very distinct so I should be able to hear the difference.  @xxmbabanexx queue is a non-blocking method so chan2.queue gets called well before sound1 finishes playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing i can think of is that chan1 and chan2 are same, even though they are different objects, they can be pointing to the same channel.

Try queueing right after getting a channel, that way you are sure to get a different channel with find_channel(), since find_channel() always returns a non-busy channel.

Try this:

```
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050,size=-16,channels=4)
sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound1.wav')
sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound2.wav')
chan1 = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
chan1.queue(sound1)
chan2 = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
chan2.queue(sound2)
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: This seems likely, I'll give it a try when I return from work.

Comment: This worked.  In addition I found much better (though undocumented approach) which is to call pygame.mixer.Channel(0) and pygame.mixer.Channel(1) to get access to specific channels by index.

Comment: I'm using this method except I'm calling functions I wrote in pygame instead of .wav files. (ex. `sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound(riff())`)  It plays through the first function, and then I get "TypeError: Unrecognized argument (type NoneType)" on that line and the second sound doesn't play.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

See [Pygame Docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel), It says:

> **Channel.queue** - queue a Sound object to follow the current

So, even though your tracks are playing on different channels, so if you force each sound to play, they will play simultaneously.

And for playing multiple sounds:

- Open all sound files, and add the `mixer.Sound` object to a list.
- The loop through the list, and start all the sounds.. using `sound.play`

This forces all the sounds to play simultaneously.
Also, make sure that you have enough empty channels to play all sounds, or else, some or the other sound sound will be interrupted.
So in code:

```
sound_files = [...] # your files
sounds = [pygame.mixer.Sound(f) for f in sound_files]
for s in sounds:
    s.play()
```

You could also create a new `Channel` or use `find_channel()` for each sound..

```
sound_files = [...] # your files
sounds = [pygame.mixer.Sound(f) for f in sound_files]
for s in sounds:
    pygame.mixer.find_channel().play(s)
```

Comment: both channels are empty, they are returned by find_channel(). In this case queue is the same as your s.play() since play just forces a channel, and queue picks picks one.

Comment: queue would work the way you expect it to if it was done on the same channel.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski This works... but OP's code doesn't even if the 2 tracks are played in the same channel..

Comment: you fail to explain why his code does not work, your solution will work, but you have to change your answer a bit to cancel my downvote.

Comment: This is a valid answer but doesn't work for me.  In my actual application I'm relying on persistent channels so I'm using on find_channel to obtain them for me.  I am basically doing what you said at the end which is using find_channel for each sound.

Comment: I've assumed the queue/play difference is less about playing multiple sounds at once and more about double buffering sound objects.  If you truly have two distinct channels you should never need to call play and should still be able to get multiple sounds playing at the same time.