# How can I play multiple sounds at the same time in pygame?

Tags: pygame

I have the music that is always run in the background and some activities that would play sound when triggered. The music works fine.

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(SOUND_FOLDER, 'WateryGrave.ogg'))
```

The problem I have is that when there are 2 or more activities triggering sounds, then only one would be played (not including the background music) and the rest are muted. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: there is a similar question with an answer that works here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385727/pygame-mixer-only-plays-one-sound-at-a-time

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can add sounds to different channels using the mixer:

```
pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\gun_fire.wav'))
pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\enemy_hit.wav'))
```

Within each channel you can still only play one sound at a time, but you can group sounds into different channels if they would need to play at the same time.

You can add more channels like this:

```
pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(10)  # default is 8
```

A simple example. For the docs on Channels, go to:

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel

Comment: You are mistaken with channels argument :
>> The channels argument is used to specify whether to use mono or stereo. 1 for mono and 2 for stereo. No other values are supported (negative values are treated as 1, values greater than 2 as 2)

Comment: @DamienJALLON woops, indeed you are correct, i had the wrong code up. I updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: So are channels a purely logical thing? or are they tied to some hardware limitation?