# Playing two sound files in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

How can I play two sound files at the same time in pygame/python? I've tried using the code below, and using mp3 files as well as wav files, but it doesn't run. I either get an error saying "Unable to open file 'file.wav'" or "Unable to open file 'file.mp3'"

```py
file1 =  pygame.mixer.Sound('file1.wav')
file2 =  pygame.mixer.Sound('file2.wav')

file1.play()
file2.play()
```

Comment: I got this from a quick google - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393916/how-can-i-play-multiple-sounds-at-the-same-time-in-pygame. Looks like you need to use channels.

Comment: Thank you @Peter. I checked that question out and tried to implement channels into my program to run two sound files, but it still gives the error "Unable to open file". I checked and made sure the sound file is spelled correctly, and it is in the same place as the program itself, but it still gives the error message.

Comment: Sounds like its probably not related to pygame then, check `os.getcwd()` to make sure you're actually in the directory you think you are.

Comment: @Peter I can play a single file without using Sound and only using Mixer, but if I try to use sound and use 2 files it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working is that I didn't have correct .wav files. What I mean is instead of converting the original .mp3 files to .wav, I just changed the file extension/name to "file.wav". Pygame didn't open the files because they weren't true .wav files.