# Mp3 player - the “file not found” messagebox.showerror shows up every time I play a file

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

The code below is a media player (mp3). It worked perfectly until I added the show_details() function which is supposed to show the length and timing of the song, the error message "file not found" appears when playing a file (The file does play! but the error message pops everytime). Once I take off the 3 lines consisting of 'a', 'total_length' and 'print' statements, the error stops to show up and the song of course plays normally. What is the problem with my code?

```
filelabel = Label(root, text="Let's make some noise!")
filelabel.pack(pady=10)

lengthlabel = Label(root, text="Total Length - 00:00")
lengthlabel.pack(pady=10)

def show_details():
    filelabel['text'] = 'Playing - ' + os.path.basename(filename)
    a = mixer.Sound(filename)
    total_length = a.get_length()
    print (total_length)

def play_music():
    global paused

    if paused:
        mixer.music.unpause()
        statusbar['text'] = 'Music Resumed: Playing ' + os.path.basename(filename)
        paused = False
    else:
        try:
            mixer.music.load(filename)
            mixer.music.play()
            statusbar['text'] = 'Playing - ' + os.path.basename(filename)
            show_details()
        except:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror('FIle not found', 'Melody could not find the song, please check again')
```

Comment: Move `show_details()` outside the `try ... except...` block to see the real error. It's bad behaviour, to use a catch-all exception.

Comment: I did, still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I see you create a music and sound object at the same time. This might be a clue to your answer:
[How can I play multiple sounds at the same time in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393916/how-can-i-play-multiple-sounds-at-the-same-time-in-pygame)

It seems that adding channels might fix your problem. But take out these three lines first to see if they are the cause:

```
a = mixer.Sound(filename)
total_length = a.get_length()
print (total_length)
```

Comment: Yes they are the problem

Comment: No it was actually an mp3 error, my program couldn't run mp3 files - needed to add that in the code @PythonAmateur742